# How to get PHPUnit to exclude .svn directories within test path?

Tags: php, phpunit, autoload

From phpunit.xml how can I get PHPUnit to not search in .svn directories? On large projects this becomes more of an issue as the number of .svn directories increases.

My current config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<phpunit bootstrap="phpunit_bootstrap.php"
    colors="true"
    convertErrorsToExceptions="true"
    convertNoticesToExceptions="true"
    convertWarningsToExceptions="true"
    processIsolation="false"
    syntaxCheck="true"
    verbose="true"
    strict="true">
    <filter>
        <whitelist addUncoveredFilesFromWhitelist="true">
            <directory suffix=".php">./phpunit/</directory>
            <exclude>
                <directory>./phpunit/.svn</directory>
            </exclude>
        </whitelist>
    </filter>
</phpunit>
```

This seems to be ignored as when I run `strace -e open phpunit phpunit/` I see:

```
open("phpunit/", O_RDONLY|O_NONBLOCK|O_LARGEFILE|O_DIRECTORY) = 3
open("phpunit/.svn", O_RDONLY|O_NONBLOCK|O_LARGEFILE|O_DIRECTORY) = 4
open("phpunit/.svn/tmp", O_RDONLY|O_NONBLOCK|O_LARGEFILE|O_DIRECTORY) = 5
open("phpunit/.svn/tmp/prop-base", O_RDONLY|O_NONBLOCK|O_LARGEFILE|O_DIRECTORY) = 6
open("phpunit/.svn/tmp/text-base", O_RDONLY|O_NONBLOCK|O_LARGEFILE|O_DIRECTORY) = 6
open("phpunit/.svn/tmp/props", O_RDONLY|O_NONBLOCK|O_LARGEFILE|O_DIRECTORY) = 6
open("phpunit/.svn/prop-base", O_RDONLY|O_NONBLOCK|O_LARGEFILE|O_DIRECTORY) = 5
open("phpunit/.svn/text-base", O_RDONLY|O_NONBLOCK|O_LARGEFILE|O_DIRECTORY) = 5
open("phpunit/.svn/props", O_RDONLY|O_NONBLOCK|O_LARGEFILE|O_DIRECTORY) = 5
```

Is it possible to blacklist .svn directories? Preferably with a wildcard directive so I don't have to specify the absolute path of each .svn dir (e.g. `<directory>.svn</directory>`)

Comment: I've got a project with +5000 classes / files in +300 folders in svn that phpunit scans and it takes about half a second until the first test is executed. Can you maybe elaborate on why this is an issues for you? :)

Comment: I'm working over a network that talks to a machine serviced by a NAS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is currently no way to tell `PHPUnit` to not scan directories matching a certain expression or to ignore hidden dirs.

So currently you would have to `<exclude>` every single svn dir.

Just to reiterate what is stated in the comments: This is only an issue when working with very slow file systems that take a lot of time for stat and read calls.

This is why I'd assume the use cases are so limited that building a .svn ignore into phpunit is not worthwhile, especially because newer svn versions don't put the dirs everywhere anymore. (See possible solution 2)

### Possible solutions:

#### List all the excludes

Maybe writing a small script that generate the exclude tags from the files isn't to much of an issue

```
find . | grep -e ".svn$" | sed 's/^/<directory>/' | sed 's/$/<\/directory>/'
```

will give you a list of all include tags to paste in for example. Or using a small domDocument based script to update the file in place :)

#### Upgrade to Subversion 1.7.

This will store all the meta data in one directory in the project root so there will be no files in your `project/tests` folder for phpunit to scan and get rid of the issue.

Comment: Thanks, great answer. I didn't know SVN 1.7 had changed it's metadata layout to something akin to git. I might have to petition an upgrade!

Answer (score 1):

This may be overkill, but I really wanted a better solution.

Here is a patch for your php\PEAR\File\Iterator\Factory.php file that is the cause of all this slowness. It skips directories that don't start with a letter or number. Adoped from [here](http://charlesmarshall.co.uk/web/2010/11/11/recursive-regex-iterator.html).

```
108,110c108
<                     new RecursiveIteratorIterator(
<                       new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($path)
<                     ),
---
>                       new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveRegexIterator(new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($path, RecursiveDirectoryIterator::FOLLOW_SYMLINKS), '=\\\\[a-zA-Z0-9]='), true),
```